How to have the conf.d for Nginx in Termux
It's possible to use Nginx in Termux after installing it with the pkg install command in Termux.
However, after installing it, i found out there's no conf.d directory in $PREFIX/etc/nginx directory.
I usually create a separate .conf file for each project domain. How to have that conf.d directory for Nginx in Termux?

To have the directory, mkdir it.
To have Nginx use the directory, reference it from the main nginx.conf like this:
include conf.d/*.conf;

Since it's not a built-in Nginx feature, the actual name and location of the directory doesn't matter.
